# Broadcom wireless doesn't work

Tags: 12.10, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 12.10, it works fine, but the wireless doesn't work. I have broadcom 4313.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Here we ask that you only ask a single question in each post; consider moving one of your two questions to a new post.

Comment: I deleted your second question, as one question per post keeps things much easier for everyone. Feel free to create another question post with your second question.

Answer (score 1):

For the wireless card, you need to install a proprietary driver. Connect a cable to your computer (just needed once, to install the driver). Then do this from sofware-center:

1. Open Ubuntu Software Center
2. Go to Edit -> Software Sources
3. Select the last tab (Additional Drivers)
4. Under "Broadcom Corporation BCM 4313", select a driver other than "Do not use the device".
5. Click "Apply changes" to install the driver.

Comment: I deleted the answer to the second question, but you can view the past versions of this answer by clicking to the date next to "edited" underneath the answer.

Comment: can you tell me how i install ubuntu and win 7 without probleme like that